# Connect PCIe x1 port to an ASIC PCIe x4

Tags: microcontroller, pcie, asic

I want to connect a microcontroller with a PCIe x1 port to an ASIC with PCIe x4 interface. It is not possible to connect microcontroller to lane 0 of ASIC, and it should be connected to other lanes (like what depicted in picture). is it possible to connect lanes this way and work with microcontroller PCIe x1 mode? In general, could we connect PCIe lanes not in numbered order?

ASIC PCIe is gen 1 compatible with PCIe Base Rev 3.0 and supports x1, x2 and x4 modes.

It would be great if link some documents.

[image: PCIe connection]

Comment: Why is connection to lane 0 impossible? That is the only way that should at least potentially work

Comment: What "ASIC" is it?

Comment: "It would be great if link some documents" -> We are thinking exactly the same thing - give us links to documents of your devices.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the problem is exactly "potentially". Lane reversal is supported for all lane together [link](http://www.nxp.com/files-static/training_presentation/TP_HARDWARE_DESIGN_PCI_SMGIII.pdf) for multiple lanes PCIe ports, but I want to connect x1 to x4.

Comment: @TomCarpenter consider ASIC as a random x4 PCIe EP, it is just for explanation.

Comment: I mean, it's possible that your asic supports a single lane on any of it's lanes, but that is really unlikely. You normally connect to the 0th lane transceiver of you only have one lane, to the 0th and the first transceiver if you have two lanes, and so on. That's why I'm, **again** asking you why it's impossible to just connect to the 0th transceiver. That restriction sounds unusual, and may I say so, stupid, if you don't explain it.

Comment: Note there's not even a guarantee your x4 device will actually work with a single lane - out just as well might refuse to do its job. **your question remains unclear as long as you don't tell us what the involved devices are and how your restrictions come to be**

Comment: @MarcusMüller a standard compliant x4 device is guaranteed by the PCIe standard (4.2.4.10.1) to work as a 1x device. All PCIe devices must support a Gen1 x1 as well as their native link width.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks a lot for your comment, it was my fault for using MCU and ASIC in question. it is a general question about a PCIe x1 connection to a PCIe x4 based on what is noted in PCIe recommendations and specifications. if it is ok, it is good to edit the original question.

Comment: @moji_fara Support for lane reversal as per PCIe standard (4.2.4.10.1) is completely **optional**, therefore considering the ASIC "as a random x4 PCIe EP" will not allow us to give you an answer as to whether or not it is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of connecting a x4 endpoint to a x1 host, that is perfectly doable. It is required as per section 4.2.4.10.1 of the PCIe V3.0 Base Specification that:

> The ability for a xN Port to form a xN Link **as well as a x1 Link** (where N can be 32, 16, 12, 8, 4, 2, and 1) is **required**.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Therefore you will have no problem connecting Lane 0 of your ASIC to the MCU.

However, the question is whether or not you can connect to any lane other than Lane 0 on the ASIC. The answer to your question can be answered as nothing more than "maybe" due to lack of any specific documentation on the devices. From the same section of the standard:

> Support for Lane reversal is **optional**.
>
> • If implemented, Lane reversal must be done for both the Transmitter and Receiver of a given Port for a multi-Lane Link.
>
> • An example of Lane reversal consists of Lane 0 of an Upstream Port attached to Lane N-1 of a Downstream Port where either the Downstream or Upstream device may reverse the Lane order to configure a xN Link.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

**Some** PCIe devices support lane reversal, which typically allows Lane 0 to be mapped to Lane N-1, keeping all lanes in order (e.g. 0,1,2,3 connect to 3,2,1,0). However this is not required by the specification so is completely device dependent.

If your ASIC supports lane reversal, then you can connect your MCU to Lane 3 of the ASIC. However if the ASIC doesn't implement the optional feature, then connecting the MCU to anything other than Lane 0 will fail.